# Rails, how to loop through form submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

A little new to Rails but have a basic question here.

I have a form created where the user enters some details about each day in a trip. The thing is, I want to loop through this form x number of times based on x = the number of days of the trip, after they have hit submit each time.

How would I accomplish this? Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Check out this railscast, it covers this pretty well:  http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

Comment: Please put your form here :)